# How do I write a pandas DataFrame to MySQL without error 1241?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy

I'm using the Pandas `to_sql()` method to try and save a Dataframe to aySQL database but when I run my code it gives an error:

`sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')`

The code will create a table with the column names from my dataframe, but none of the rest of the dataframe is passed over.

Here's the structure of my dataframe `df` (the real dataframe has only about 900 rows):

```
  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
0  a    b    c     d
1 cat  dog  fish  pig
2 True True False True
```

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def sql_write(somedf):
    
    engine = create_engine('mysql://{user}:{pw}@localhost/{db}'.format(user='username',
                                                                              pw='password',
                                                                              db='project_db'),paramstyle='format')
    
    

    somedf.to_sql(name='project_table1', engine,  chunksize=1000, if_exists='append')

table = sql_write(df)
```

The table `project_table1` does not exist at the start.

However when I run this code only the column headers are written to the new table, the other rows in the dataframe are not.

This is the error I get:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError) (1241, 'Operand should contain 1 column(s)')
[SQL: INSERT INTO project_table1 (`Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`, `Col4`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)]
[parameters: (('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), ('cat', 'dog', 'fish', 'goat'), (True, True, False, True))]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

The table is created and the column names are inserted but none of the parameters a written to the table. I'm unsure as to how to fix this.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your issue using `mysql+pymysql://...`. The `True` and `False` values are automatically converted to `'1'` and `'0'`, respectively.